# Using a SIGINT from Ctrl+C

Tags: c, copy-paste, sigint

alright, so i'm using a sighandler to interpret some signal, for this purpose it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, so when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is typed some action will be taken, and everything is fine and dandy, but what I really need is for this to happen without `^C` appearing in the input/output

for example let's say i have this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void siginthandler(int param)
{
  printf("User pressed Ctrl+C\n");
  exit(1);
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGINT, siginthandler);
  while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

the output would be

`^CUser pressed Ctrl+C`

How could I get this to simply be

`User pressed Ctrl+C`?

Comment: Note that the ^C isn't actually in the output.  Redirect the output of your program to a file with `>output` and observe that the ^C still appears in your terminal window, but does not appear in the output file.

Comment: thanks so much for the help all, very good suggestions! i now consider myself a better programmer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this effect using the curses library's "noecho()" call -- but you must be willing to accept (and/or use) curses terminal handling too ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <curses.h>

void siginthandler(int param)
{
  endwin();
  printf("User pressed Ctrl+C\n");
  exit(1);
}

int main()
{
  initscr();
      noecho();
  signal(SIGINT, siginthandler);
  while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: On closer inspection -- the ^C doesn't appear even without the noecho() call.  Perhpas curses initscr() sets up this behavior by default.

Answer (score 1):

That is most likely not your program doing that. It's likely to be the terminal drivers, in which case you should look into `stty` with the `ctlecho` or `echoctl` options.

You can use `stty -a` to get all the current settings for your terminal device. For a programmatic interface to these items, [`termios`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios) is the way to go.

Comment: alright, that makes sense, thanks. how would i implement that in my code though? is it a C command, research is kinda sparse on it...

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, this kind of thing falls under the control of your terminal driver and is typically done using the curses library.  That said, here is a hack that will probably get you on your way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void siginthandler(int param) {
    printf("User pressed Ctrl+C\n");
    system("stty echo");
    exit(1);
}

int main() {
    system("stty -echo");
    signal(SIGINT, siginthandler);
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```